# paypal integration with express checkout and onsite

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

Im trying to integrate Paypal express checkout(offsite) and payflow(onsite) to our payment page.

I have successfully integrated paypal express checkout button using the NVP and SOAP API and everything works fine.

I have also started the integration for payflow (old XML API) as an option as well.

My question is how do I allow customers to have 2 options in the order form that goes to the same merchant account?
Currently its a tab(moving to a radio button) to display the payment options.

If credit card is selected, it will show a credit card form onsite and send the request. 
If paypal, it will show the paypal button and redirect it to paypal and process the transaction.

If I have my sandbox paypal account (with its API key), could I use the same account for the payflow request so the money goes in the same account? or do I to signup up?

If there is any examples, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try exploring the "Payflow Link" product provided by PayPal which would enable you to show both the Express Checkout and Credit Card option in the same page. Examples are available in the below documentation.

Here is the Developer Documentation for [Payflow Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/)